# Three textView in one row

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to do 3 TextView in a row. I worked up an example and now I have:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                        android:textColor="#f00"
                        android:text="one" 
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" ></TextView>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                        android:textColor="#f00"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:text="two" ></TextView>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                        android:textColor="#f00"
                        android:text="three" 
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

I would like have: `id:TextView01` on the left, `id:TextView02` on the middle and `id:TextView03` on the right.

Now `id:TextView01` and `id:TextView03` working good, but `id:TextView02` is applied to the `id:TextView01`.

I can use other layout, but I want to have it centered automatically from left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create LinearLayout. Make textviews match parent and equal layout weight to take exactly 1/3 of the row

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                        android:textColor="#f00"
                        android:text="one" 
 ></TextView>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                        android:textColor="#f00"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:text="two" ></TextView>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                        android:textColor="#f00"
                        android:text="three" 
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

work with `layout_toRightOf`:

```
       <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                    android:textColor="#f00"
                    android:text="one" 
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" ></TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                    android:textColor="#f00"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TextView01"
                    android:text="two" ></TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                    android:textColor="#f00"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TextView02"
                    android:text="three" 
                    ></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

or with `LinearLayout` type `horizontal`.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use Relative Layout for this kind of stuffs. Try to Linear Layout.

and your code can be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:id="@+id/relative"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="one"
    android:textColor="#f00" >

</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="two"
    android:textColor="#f00" >

</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="three"
    android:textColor="#f00" >

</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a 3 textviews in a line, Then you can put three of them in a `LinearLayout` and set `layout_width=0` and `layout_weight=1` to all 3 textviews